# Do all tables need to be built as models?

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and trying to figure out models. I have a question that I just cannot find the answer to. I am designing an equipment checkout app. I would like to have a data entry page (/Admin) where we can enter the equipment names and types...no problem (I think). However, I also need a *Checkout* table that will be updated as equipment is checked in and out and an *Employee* table that would hopefully pull from AD. My question is, do these two tables that will not be updated manually on the Admin page still need to be defined as models? Is this where the 'EDITABLE' field option comes in? Thanks!

Comment: I quite don't get what you need. All models are editable from a superuser's admin interface. Just go on and make two classes in your models.py and edit them as you wish. If you need something more specific please edit the question.

Comment: You can have a model that is not available on the admin interface, or it is as edit-only..... if thats what you want please reply and I will tell you how to do that

Comment: Yes, Walucas. That is what I was looking for. A table that will not be populated by the admins but will be populated by the users of the app: customer data, rental/checkout transactions, etc. This would still be defined as a model you say?

Answer (score 2):

Models in Django are the main interface to communicate with data layer. They map directly to database, provide access to it using ORM and also track changes via migrations. They can be integrated with pretty much all Django components: generic views, forms, serializers, etc.

Just because certain piece of data is not being updated manually, doesn't mean that you don't need to define models for it.

If you want to use database tables separately from models, you'd need to manually create DB connection and use raw SQL or create custom data model. Unless you're using a third party external service, I don't think there are many use cases where that would be required.

Comment: Thank you, Maxim. This was really more of a concept question and I think you answered it. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

well i would do it like that

## models.py

```
class Equipment (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=30) #choice field here would be better
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employee = models.ManyToManyField("Employee")


class = Employee (models.Model):
     #here you add all employee data
```

this way you could create an instance from the admin for every equipment and employee and on every checkout you can update the equipment